Need solution to write an assertion in Cypress using TypeScript
Below is the code snippet
const comTextArray=[]

dash.dropdown().then(($elements)=>{

cy.wrap($elements).find('a').each($ele =>{

const comText=$ele.text();

comTextArray.push(comText)

})

}).then(()=>{

expect(comTextArray).to.include("Test")

})

In the above code the assertion is not executed as expected, how to handle the logic here to execute the assertion?
Right now the saved array comTextArray is not getting passed correctly to the assertion, causing the script to fail

For one thing "except" !== "expect". Give a [mre].

In Cypress assertions work much better with .should(). Please review the documentation.
This command gives you retry on the expect()
.should(() => expect(comTextArray).to.include("Test"))

Better, drop the each(element) part and just make a simple assertion on the text.
cy.get(<dropdown-options>)
  .invoke('text')
  .should('contain', 'my-value')

or simply
cy.contains(<dropdown-options>, 'my-value')

